# What is the significance of 36 in the Vietnamese poem "Learning Late Letters"?

Tags: poetry, symbolism, cultural-context, vietnamese-language, nguyen-hoang-quyen

["Learning Late Letters"](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/september-2020-poetry-contest-learning-late-letters-nguyen-hoang-guyen), a poem originally written in Vietnamese by Nguyễn Hoàng Quyên, was one of the winners of the 2020 Words Without Borders [Academy of Americans Poets Poems in Translation Contest](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/poetry-contest-winners-2020-words-without-bordersacademy-of-american-poets). The narrator is remembering their dead father and his letters. The middle part of the text consists of 36 short two-word sentences beginning with "Die", and in the following paragraph the number 36 is repeated many times.

**Is there any particular significance to the number 36 here?** Is it regarded as a magical number in Vietnamese culture? Does the usage of this number, to a Vietnamese reader of the original text, imply something, like a particular type of magic or people?

Comment: [36 Animals](https://saigoneer.com/saigon-culture/9863-gambling-and-globalization-in-old-saigon-a-brief-history-of-s%E1%BB%91-%C4%91%E1%BB%81-in-vietnam), a traditional Vietnamese game. [36 streets for 36 trades](https://theculturetrip.com/asia/vietnam/articles/hanois-old-quarter-36-streets-for-36-trades/) in Hanoi's old quarter. No idea if either of these could be relevant.